# Is Crew Dragon rated for any non-Spacex boosters?

Tags: spacex, dragon-v2, human-rating

The Spacex crew Dragon uses the Falcon 9 for its orbital launches, and is not set to ever use a different launcher.
However, an uncrewed Dragon will probably launch on the Falcon Heavy, as is planned with Dragon XL for the Artemis program.

The Boeing Starliner [is designed to be compatible with four launch vehicles: Atlas V, Delta IV, Falcon 9, and Vulcan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_Starliner), even though it will likely only ever use Atlas V and eventually Vulcan.

[This answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/45665/29286) strongly suspects that Crew Dragon is rated for at least Atlas. **Is this the case?**

**Did Spacex design Dragon to be rated for other launch vehicles, like Atlas V?**

**What are the incentives for them to do so?** (Any directives from the US government?)

**Could ULA do it the other way and design Vulcan to be compatible with Dragon?**

Comment: Contrary to the linked answer, I would strongly suspect otherwise. I can't prove it (how do you prove a negative?), but SpaceX has a marked proclivity to do everything in-house and to be highly vertically integrated.

Comment: As far as I know no manned spacecraft in the past was ever launched on a rocked of another model, not the primary rocket assigned for it. The cited question is about "is it technically possible?" and I tend to agree it is. But for question "is it rated for another launcher now?" I'm almost sure it isn't. And will it happen in future - very unlikely I think. I'd like to mention we have no evidence Boeing Starliner is actually designed to be compatible with Falcon-9 - the article in wikipedia has only broken link to a document of 2010. Too much management problems, not enough motivation, I think

Comment: @Heopps "no manned spacecraft in the past was ever launched on a rocked of another model, not the primary rocket assigned for it" yes, but there are definitely plans to fly a Starliner on a Vulcan, so rating a spacecraft for a different rocket family isn't *that* far fetched

Comment: I'm finding it hard to see the use case. Sure, NASA is big on dissimilar redundancy, and on risk mitigation, but there have to be limits. The only reason to fly Dragon on Atlas would be if fatal flaws are discovered in F9 and Starliner at the same time. And that case is, I believe, so unlikely, that NASA would risk giving up the ISS at that point.